# Can we Use AFNetworking/NSURLSession support Set SNI And support HTTP/2?

Tags: ios, https, afnetworking, sni

**Background Introduction:**

In the front of the building support HTTPS proxy server, usually the certificate will have a headache problem.According to the working principle of HTTPS, the browser to access a HTTPS site, the first to establish the SSL connection with server, the first step to establish a connection request to the server's certificate.The server sends the certificate, is don't know what's your browser to access the domain name, so can't according to the different domain name to send the certificate.SNI (Server Name Indication) is to solve a Server using multiple domain Name and certificate of SSL/TLS.Its working principle is as follows:Before you connect to the server to establish the SSL link send to access the site's domain name (Hostname).According to the domain name server returns a suitable certificate.At present, most of the operating system and browser has a good support for SNI extension, OpenSSL 0.9.8 also has a built-in function.The above process, when the client use HTTPDNS analytic domain, the host of the request URL will be replaced with HTTPDNS parsing IP, to get the server to the domain name for the resolved IP, unable to find a matching certificate, only to return to the default certificate or does not return, so there will be a SSL/TLS handshake failed error.

**Condition:**

1. Use AFNetworking.(Client)
2. URL's hostname with ip address. For example:
   https://1.2.3.6/index.html
3. Server(Single Ip) using multiple domain Name and
   certificate.(Server)

I want to use an URL with ip address hostname(eg:https://1.2.3.6/index.html).
To get correct certificate , I must set correct SNI before socket connetcion established.
iOS system does not provide the interface of SNI (NSURLConnection/NSURLSession).

Any suggest For my trouble?